# Service not running for Impersonated user with CreateProcessAsUser [C#]

Tags: c#

There is a LocalSystem Service (Job.exe) which performs a certain absolutly required task (key), this service is run for all users (at least when they logon).
There is another LocalSystem Service (Serv.exe) which uses CreateProcessAsUser(...) to launch a process as a different (admin) user.
There are 2 accounts, USER (which is the one logged-on) and ADMIN.

So this is the scenario ...
User logs in to USER account (non-admin) and both LocalSystem Services (Job.exe & Serv.exe) start and work without any problems... Then at a certain point Serv.exe calls CreateProcessAsUser() using the ADMIN account in order to launch an administrative task (note that USER is currently logged in).

So far everything is fine - but now a problem happens - the process run by CreateProcessAsUser(...) under the ADMIN is not subject to the LocalSystem service JOB.exe - for example if JOB.exe monitors file-system changes and logs them if I launch a task with CreateProcessAsUser(...) under ADMIN that changes files I would assume JOB.exe would log these - but it does NOT ...

So it looks like JOB.exe is NOT running in the context of the ADMIN account when launched using CreateProcessAsUser(...), this is a big deal for me - I need to ensure JOB.exe LocalSystem service is absolutly always running - even when CreateProcessAsUser(...) is used...

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem? any help would be much appreciated.
Can I load the environment? profile? something to kick-in JOB.exe so that it actually works?

Thanks,

Comment: JOB.exe is legacy software that monitors registry and file system changes - sadly I don't have the source code available to show exactly how it works but ... it works fine for the logged-in user.

Do I maybe have to do something special to my CreateProcessAsUser() to load the environment? Profile? etc... I also noticed that accessing HKEY_CURRENT_USER doesn't seem to work ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the process as an admin by putting it in an exe and then using the C# Process object to kick it off, using code similar to the below:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = toolFilePath;            
process.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;            
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(toolFilePath);            
process.StartInfo.Domain = domain;           
process.StartInfo.UserName = userName;            
process.StartInfo.Password = decryptedPassword;            
process.Start();           
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... what process? Are you referring to the JOB.exe service? (can't touch this - legacy code) or Serv.exe launching the task? this won't work because LocalSystem cannot use Process.Start() to impersonate (MSDN documentation states it won't work - and I've tested).

Can you clarify?

Comment: The Serv.exe launching the task - if the task was an exe file then the above would launch a process for that exe using some specified credentials. I'm not sure about LocalSystem being able to do it, but I know that a non-admin user can.